# Programmably Typing the Tables, Views, and Columns Properties of a Database

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, adodb

Programmably Typing a Database gives you the advantages of Intellisense and Compiler Type Checking.

Notice that single public DatabaseAlias variable of public Type DatabaseAlias is used.  The members of the DatabaseAlias Type are a mix of custom classes and private Types that hold all the metadata of the Object that they are describing.  This creates a very tidy tree structure that can easily be transversed while coding.

[image: Database Demo Gif]

### Classes

This project contains 5 Classes:

- DatabaseTyper:  Copies the other 4 classes to the target VBProject and creates a Standard Module to hold the Database Type and Initialization Function.  This class is not copied to the target VBProject
- ColumnInformation: Wraps the Column metadata returned adSchemaColumns
- DatabaseInformation: ConnectionString and getConnection As ADODB.Connection function
- TableInformation: Wraps the Column metadata returned adSchemaTables
- ViewInformation: Wraps the Column metadata returned adSchemaTables

These Classes contain minimum functionality but could easily be expanded.

### Sample Setup

```
Sub UpdateAdventureWorks()
    Dim db As New DatabaseTyper
    db.Init getConnectionString, "AdventureWorks"
    db.UpdateVBProject Workbooks("AdventureWorks.xlsm").VBProject
End Sub
```

In the "Sample Function" below I create a variable for each Column used in the query and assign it the default value of the that Column (Note: the Column's default value is it's fully qualified name).  If one of the column names is changed, updating the Database Type will cause a Compiler "Variable Not Defined" Error.

[AdventureWorks Access Database](https://adventureworksaccess.codeplex.com/) Sample function

```
Function getEmployeeLeaveQuery()
    Dim SQL As String, ContactID As String, ContactID2 As String, FirstName As String, LastName As String, Title As String, VacationHours As String, SickLeaveHours As String

    AdventureWorks_Initialize

    With AdventureWorks.Tables.Person_Contact.Columns
        ContactID = .ContactID
        FirstName = .FirstName
        LastName = .LastName
        Title = .Title
    End With

    With AdventureWorks.Tables.HumanResources_Employee.Columns
        ContactID2 = .ContactID
        VacationHours = .VacationHours
        SickLeaveHours = .SickLeaveHours
    End With

    With AdventureWorks.Tables
        SQL = "SELECT " & FirstName & "," & LastName & "," & Title & "," & VacationHours & "," & SickLeaveHours & vbCrLf
        SQL = SQL & "FROM " & .Person_Contact.Object & " INNER JOIN "
        SQL = SQL & .HumanResources_Employee.Object & " ON " & ContactID & " = " & ContactID2 & ";"
    End With

    getEmployeeLeaveQuery = SQL
End Function
```

getEmployeeLeaveQuery Output

```
SELECT [Person_Contact].[FirstName],[Person_Contact].[LastName],[Person_Contact].[Title],[HumanResources_Employee].[VacationHours],[HumanResources_Employee].[SickLeaveHours]
FROM Person_Contact INNER JOIN HumanResources_Employee ON [Person_Contact].[ContactID] = [HumanResources_Employee].[ContactID];
```

---

### Sample Database Type Module

```
'Tables: 2 Views: 1 Columns: 8
Private Type Positions_Columns
    ID As New ColumnInformation
    Position As New ColumnInformation
End Type
Private Type Positions
    Columns As Positions_Columns
    Object As New TableInformation
End Type

Private Type EmployeeView_Columns
    FullName As New ColumnInformation
    Position As New ColumnInformation
End Type
Private Type EmployeeView
    Columns As EmployeeView_Columns
    Object As New ViewInformation
End Type

Private Type Employees_Columns
    FirstName As New ColumnInformation
    ID As New ColumnInformation
    LastName As New ColumnInformation
    PositionID As New ColumnInformation
End Type
Private Type Employees
    Columns As Employees_Columns
    Object As New TableInformation
End Type

Private Type Tables
    Employees As Employees
    Positions As Positions
End Type

Private Type Views
    EmployeeView As EmployeeView
End Type

Private Type EmployeesDB
    Object As New DatabaseInformation
    Tables As Tables
    Views As Views
End Type

Public EmployeesDB As EmployeesDB

Public Sub EmployeesDB_Initialize()
    With EmployeesDB
        .Object.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow\Employees.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        With .Tables
            With .Employees
                .Object.Init "||||Employees||TABLE||||||||12/20/2017 6:18:22 AM||12/20/2017 6:19:59 AM"
                With .Columns
                    .FirstName.Init "||||Employees||FirstName||||||2||0||||106||-1||130||||255||510||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                    .ID.Init "||||Employees||ID||||||1||0||||90||0||3||||||||10||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                    .LastName.Init "||||Employees||LastName||||||3||0||||106||-1||130||||255||510||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                    .PositionID.Init "||||Employees||PositionID||||||4||0||||122||-1||3||||||||10||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                End With
            End With
            With .Positions
                .Object.Init "||||Positions||TABLE||||||||12/20/2017 6:20:05 AM||12/20/2017 6:20:31 AM"
                With .Columns
                    .ID.Init "||||Positions||ID||||||1||0||||90||0||3||||||||10||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                    .Position.Init "||||Positions||Position||||||2||0||||106||-1||130||||255||510||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                End With
            End With
            'Insert Tables
        End With

        With .Views
            With .EmployeeView
                .Object.Init "||||EmployeeView||VIEW||||||||12/20/2017 6:22:11 AM||12/20/2017 6:22:30 AM"
                With .Columns
                    .FullName.Init "||||EmployeeView||FullName||||||1||0||||98||-1||130||||255||510||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                    .Position.Init "||||EmployeeView||Position||||||2||0||||102||-1||130||||255||510||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
                End With
            End With
            'Insert Views
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

### DatabaseTyper: Class

```
Option Explicit
Public list As Object
Private Const COL_CLASS = "ColumnInformation", TBL_CLASS = "TableInformation", VIEW_CLASS = "ViewInformation", DATABASE_CLASS = "DatabaseInformation"
Private Const TYPE_HEADER = "Private Type ", TYPE_FOOTER = "End Type"
Private Const Tables = "Tables", Views = "Views"
Private Const COL_SUFFIX = "_Column", TBL_SUFFIX = "_Table", VIEW_SUFFIX = "_View"
Private DBAlias As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
End Sub

Private Sub AddADODB_Reference(VBProject1 As VBProject)
    Dim r
    On Error Resume Next
    Set r = VBProject1.References("ADODB")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then VBProject1.References.AddFromGuid "{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}", 2, 5
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

Private Sub AddOutline(ConnectionString As String)
    Dim Init_Name As String
    Init_Name = DBAlias & "_Initialize"
    With list
        'Add Database Table
        .Add TYPE_HEADER & Tables
        .Add TYPE_FOOTER
        .Add vbNullString
        .Add TYPE_HEADER & Views
        .Add TYPE_FOOTER
        .Add vbNullString
        'Add Database Type Outline
        .Add TYPE_HEADER & DBAlias
        .Add "Object As New " & DATABASE_CLASS
        .Add "Tables As " & Tables
        .Add "Views As " & Views
        .Add TYPE_FOOTER
        .Add vbNullString
        .Add "Public " & DBAlias & " As " & DBAlias
        'Add Database Initialization Outline
        .Add vbNullString
        .Add "Public Sub " & Init_Name
        .Add "With " & DBAlias
        .Add ".Object.ConnectionString =" & Chr(34) & ConnectionString & Chr(34)
        .Add "With ." & Tables
        .Add "'Insert " & Tables
        .Add "End With"
        .Add vbNullString
        .Add "With ." & Views
        .Add "'Insert " & Views
        .Add "End With"
        .Add "End With"
        .Add "End Sub"
        .Add vbNullString
    End With
End Sub

Private Function CleanName(ByVal Name As String) As String
    Dim x As Long
    If Not Left(Name, 1) Like "[A-Za-z]" Then Name = "A" & Name
    For x = 1 To Len(Name)
        If Not Mid(Name, x, 1) Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then Mid(Name, x, 1) = "_"
    Next
    CleanName = Name
End Function

Private Function getVBAString(Text As String) As String
    Const MAXCHAR = 800
    Dim x As Long
    Dim s As String
    Text = Replace(Text, Chr(34), String(2, 34))
    Text = Replace(Text, vbCrLf, "~~")
    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        For x = 1 To Len(Text) Step MAXCHAR
            .Add Mid(Text, x, MAXCHAR)
        Next
        s = Join(.ToArray, Chr(34) & ": _" & vbCrLf & Chr(34))
        getVBAString = Chr(34) & Left(s, Len(s) - 1) & Chr(34)
    End With
End Function

Private Function getVBComponentText(module As CodeModule) As String
    With module
        getVBComponentText = .Lines(1, .CountOfLines)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub Init(ConnectionString As String, DBAlias1 As String)
    Dim COLUMN_NAME As String, InitText As String, TABLE_TYPE As String, TABLE_NAME As String
    Dim Counts(2) As Long
    With New ADODB.Connection
        .ConnectionString = ConnectionString
        .Open

        DBAlias = DBAlias1
        AddOutline ConnectionString

        With .OpenSchema(adSchemaTables)
            While (Not .EOF)
                TABLE_NAME = CleanName(.Fields("TABLE_NAME"))
                TABLE_TYPE = .Fields(3).Value
                InitText = getVBAString(.GetString(adClipString, 1, "||", , vbNullString))
                If TABLE_TYPE = "TABLE" Then
                    InsertTable TABLE_NAME, InitText, True
                    Counts(0) = Counts(0) + 1
                ElseIf TABLE_TYPE = "VIEW" Then
                    InsertTable TABLE_NAME, InitText, False
                    Counts(1) = Counts(1) + 1
                End If
            Wend
        End With

        With .OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns)
            While (Not .EOF)
                TABLE_NAME = CleanName(.Fields("TABLE_NAME"))
                COLUMN_NAME = CleanName(.Fields("COLUMN_NAME"))
                If Not TABLE_NAME Like "MSys*" Then
                    InitText = getVBAString(.GetString(adClipString, 1, "||", vbNullString))
                    InsertColumn COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME, InitText, False
                    Counts(2) = Counts(2) + 1
                Else: .MoveNext
                End If
            Wend
        End With
    End With

    list.Insert 0, "'Tables: " & Counts(0) & " Views: " & Counts(1) & " Columns: " & Counts(2)

    If Counts(1) = 0 Then list.Insert list.IndexOf_3(TYPE_HEADER & Views) + 1, "NoView As Boolean"
End Sub

Private Sub InsertColumn(COLUMN_NAME As String, TABLE_NAME As String, InitText As String, IsTable As Boolean)
    Dim After As Long, InsertAt As Long
    With list
        'Insert Into Tables\Views
        After = .IndexOf_3(TYPE_HEADER & TABLE_NAME & "_Columns")
        If After = -1 Then Exit Sub
        InsertAt = .IndexOf(TYPE_FOOTER, After)
        .Insert InsertAt, COLUMN_NAME & " As New " & COL_CLASS

        'Insert Into Init
        After = .IndexOf_3("With ." & TABLE_NAME)
        InsertAt = .IndexOf("End With", After)
        .Insert InsertAt, "." & COLUMN_NAME & ".Init " & InitText
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub InsertTable(TABLE_NAME As String, InitText As String, IsTable As Boolean)
    Dim After As Long, InsertAt As Long

    With list
        'Insert Into Tables\Views Columns Type
        .Insert InsertAt, TYPE_HEADER & TABLE_NAME & "_Columns"
        .Insert InsertAt + 1, TYPE_FOOTER

        'Insert Into Tables\Views Type
        .Insert InsertAt + 2, TYPE_HEADER & TABLE_NAME
        .Insert InsertAt + 3, "Columns As " & TABLE_NAME & "_Columns"
        .Insert InsertAt + 4, "Object As New " & IIf(IsTable, TBL_CLASS, VIEW_CLASS)
        .Insert InsertAt + 5, TYPE_FOOTER
        .Insert InsertAt + 6, vbNullString

        'Insert Into Tables\Views
        After = .IndexOf_3(TYPE_HEADER & IIf(IsTable, Tables, Views))
        InsertAt = .IndexOf(TYPE_FOOTER, After)
        .Insert InsertAt, TABLE_NAME & " As " & TABLE_NAME

        'Insert Into Init Tables
        After = .IndexOf_3("'Insert " & IIf(IsTable, Tables, Views))
        InsertAt = .IndexOf("End With", After) - 1
        .Insert InsertAt, "With ." & TABLE_NAME
        .Insert InsertAt + 1, ".Object.Init " & InitText
        .Insert InsertAt + 2, "With .Columns"
        .Insert InsertAt + 3, "End With"
        .Insert InsertAt + 4, "End With"
    End With
End Sub

Public Function ToString() As String
    Dim Clone As Object, item As Variant
    Dim indent As Long

    Set Clone = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    For Each item In list
        item = Trim(item)
        If item Like "Private *" Or item Like "Public *" Then
            Clone.Add item
            indent = 1
        ElseIf item = "End Sub" Or item = "End Function" Or item = "End Type" Or item = "End Enum" Then
            indent = 0
            Clone.Add item
        ElseIf item Like "With *" Or item Like "For *" Or item Like "If * Then" Or item Like "Select * Then" Or item = "Loop" Or item Like "For " Then
            Clone.Add Space(indent * 4) & item
            indent = indent + 1
        ElseIf item = "End With" Or item Like "Next" Or item Like "End If" Or item Like "End Select" Then
            indent = indent - 1
            Clone.Add Space(indent * 4) & item
        Else
            Clone.Add Space(indent * 4) & item
        End If
    Next

    ToString = Join(Clone.ToArray, vbCrLf)
End Function

Public Sub UpdateVBProject(VBProject1 As VBProject)
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim msg As String, ModName As String, s(1) As String
    ModName = DBAlias & "_Module"

    For Each item In Array(ModName, COL_CLASS, DATABASE_CLASS, TBL_CLASS, VIEW_CLASS)
        On Error Resume Next
        s(0) = getVBComponentText(VBProject1.VBComponents(item).CodeModule)

        If item = ModName Then
            s(1) = ToString
        Else
            s(1) = getVBComponentText(ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(item).CodeModule)
        End If

        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If s(0) = s(1) Then
                msg = msg & item & ": " & "Current" & vbCrLf
            Else
                msg = msg & item & ": " & "Update Available" & vbCrLf
                flag = True
            End If
        Else
            msg = msg & item & ": Missing" & vbCrLf
            flag = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next

    msg = msg & vbCrLf & "Press Yes to Update"
    If Not flag Then
        MsgBox "No Updates Available", vbInformation, ""
    ElseIf MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo, "Update Available") = vbYes Then
        AddADODB_Reference VBProject1
        For Each item In Array(ModName, COL_CLASS, DATABASE_CLASS, TBL_CLASS, VIEW_CLASS)
            On Error Resume Next
            VBProject1.VBComponents.Remove VBProject1.VBComponents(item)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next

        With VBProject1.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_StdModule)
            .Name = ModName
            With .CodeModule
                If .CountOfLines > 0 Then .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
                .AddFromString ToString
            End With
        End With

        For Each item In Array(COL_CLASS, DATABASE_CLASS, TBL_CLASS, VIEW_CLASS)
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(item).Export item & ".bas"
            VBProject1.VBComponents.Import item & ".bas"
            Kill item & ".bas"
        Next

    End If
End Sub
```

I'm only including the DatabaseTyper above is this post but you can download the complete workbook: [Database-Typer](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sw1s2roVK8JR9RRoHZylXElgKpQECcZI).  Note: I will probably refactor this class in the near future, to improve its readability.